# Linux environment variable setting issue in cluster from single point

Tags: linux, centos7, cluster, bashrc

I have a cluster of few machines. I have to control all configuration from single system. For that I have decided to used .bashrc in Centos 7 servers (I push same .bashrc in each system via `rsync` from single machine). I am facing one problem, every system have external hard drive that is mounted like `/dev/sdb /mnt/2c511624-12ea-48d9-853a-54af000e7239`. Name of hard drive varies for each machine. How it will be possible that this name should be correct for each machine. I have to then automatically transfer some data in each disk of each system. I have tried my best to explain my problem, if it still not clear then please comment?

Comment: Maybe would be better to utilize some distributed filesystem (Gluster/Ceph)?

Comment: Are you using .bashrc for config? That is not a good idea. Either look into some config management system like ansible or create a shell script that can push out the config. That way you can check which machine it is. If not then create custom .bashrc for each machine.

Comment: My actual software (Hadoop) reads it from its own configuration